# TinyMCE retrieving elements using DomQuery

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I'm dealing with **TinyMCE** to create a WYSIWYG editor, but there is a problem and now I'm stuck on it.

I need to create a system where users are allowed to create specific documents, each devided into **sections** i.e. a wrapper. Inside every section there are textual and block elements (p, table, img and so on).

Now, the problem is: when a new section needs to be created I'm using the following code

```
function insertRawSection () {

  // Close the current section and open the next one
  Editor.execCommand('mceInsertRawHtml',false,`</section><section><h1>${ZERO_SPACE}</h1>`)
}
```

This code works, but the real problem comes out when I need to move the **cursor** at the start of the new **h1** element.
I can't retrieve the new heading because if I look for it with DomQuery it doesn't appear.

The code I use to lookup the h1 element is the following

```
    function insertRawSection () {

  // Close the current section and open the next one
  Editor.execCommand('mceInsertRawHtml',false,`</section><section><h1 data-pointer>${ZERO_SPACE}</h1>`)

  // Lookup the last inserted heading
  console.log($('[data-pointer]'))
}
```

**Note:** The variable $ is not **JQuery** but is **TinyMCE.DomQuery** (everything is correctly setted up)

The log print only the previous existent headings, but not the last one. Probably there is somethings like a refresh to execute, but what i have to do in order to "communicate" between this command and the DomQuery APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mceInsertRawHtml same can be achieved using dom methods of tinymce.

```
var ed = tinymce.activeEditor;
var currentNode = ed.selection.getNode();
var newEle = ed.dom.create('section', {}, '<h1></h1>');
            ed.dom.insertAfter(newEle, currentNode);
            ed.selection.select(newEle.firstChild.firstChild);
            ed.selection.collapse(false);
            ed.focus();
```

Once the element is created same can be selected using dom methods to place the cursor at the begining/ending of the element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
In any case this code should work but unfortunately this will break the Undo/Redo system.

Comment: Wrap the code inside a transaction to enable undo level.
ed.undoManager.transact(function () {
    // code here
}